# Load drawableLeft image for EditText using databinding when onTextChanged called

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I want to create sample form by using `databinding` and `MVVM pattern`.
In the application, i want to display `drawableLeft` image on `EditText` according to email validation.
if validation return true then set `drawableLeft` success image otherwise fail.

Layout->

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/email_id"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/email_hint"
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
     android:onTextChanged="@{viewModel::onEmailChange}"
     android:text="@={viewModel.loginModel.emailId}"
     android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
     app:drawableEnd="@{viewModel.loginModel.image}" />
```

BindingAdapter->

```
 @JvmStatic
    @androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter("drawableEnd")
    fun setDrawableEnd(view: MyTextInputEditTextRegular, resourceId: Int) {
        Log.e("resourceId","... $resourceId")
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.context, resourceId)
        setIntrinsicBounds(drawable)
        val drawables = view.compoundDrawables
        view.setCompoundDrawables(drawables[1], drawables[2], drawable, drawables[3])
    }

    private fun setIntrinsicBounds(drawable: Drawable?) {
        drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
    }
```

ViewModel->

```
@Bindable
    private fun getImage(): Int {
        return R.drawable.ic_check
    }
```

Comment: @mohammadRezaAbiri sure, check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom binding adapter to do so:

first of all, your data should hold some sort of flag you are using to determine email is wrong or not (`isValid: Boolean`). You need to update that value every time content inside your editText changes.

in xml you need to introduce property for editText:

```
<EditText 
//properties
app:drawableLeftValidation="@{vm.isValid}"
>
```

then create custom binding adapter

```
  @BindingAdapter("drawableLeftValidation")
    fun setDrawableLeftByValidation(editText: EditText, isValid: Boolean) {
        val leftDrawable = if (isValid) {
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(editText.context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
        } else {
            null
        }
        editText.setCompoundDrawables(leftDrawable, null, null, null)
}
```

Hope it helped :)